# How to solve this Trigonometric integral involving sine?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin t}{1+\sqrt{\sin 2t}}\,dt $$
i used properties of definite integrals to reduce it upto this 
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin t+\cos t}{1+\sqrt{\sin 2t}}\,dt$$
I'm not sure how to approach from here , it was asked in AMM ,problem 11961

Comment: This one was also posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/272381/40563) some days ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\begin{align}2I&=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin t+\cos t}{1+\sqrt{\sin 2t}}\,dt\\&=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin t+\cos t}{1+\sqrt{1-(\sin t-\cos t)^2}}\,dt\\& =\underbrace{ \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos u}{1+\cos u}\,du}_{\sin t-\cos t=\sin u }\\&=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{1+\cos u}\right)\,du\end{align}$$
Solving this you'll get 
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}-1$$